# How to color highlight .htaccess files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, .htaccess, syntax-highlighting, colors

I spend some time editing configurations in .htaccess files across several projects in Eclipse. How would I go about telling Eclipse to auto color this file in a similar fashion as shell scripts or HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that would work for sure is write your own plugin for .htaccess files. But if you've never done that before it will take a bit of time to get into. There are plenty of tutorials available online, though. See [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-does-plugins/PDE-intro.html) for an example.

Answer (score 8):

I found using the "Properties File Editor" seems to give a decent color output. It's actually for Java files, so it comes with a stock Eclipse.

In Preferences, "General" -> "Content Types" -> "Text" -> "Java Properties File"
click "Add..." button, enter ".htaccess", click "OK".

Comment: I also had to change: Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations to tell .htaccess files to open up with the Java Editor by default as the colour coding was applied otherwise.

Comment: This works great for a lot of other editors too, like Super Neutron Drive!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [**ColorEditor**](http://www.gstaff.org/colorEditor/) from Gstaff, in order to define your [**own syntax coloring**](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/eclipse/general-purpose-editor-within-eclipse).