# .htaccess - Editor or plugin for Eclipse/Netbeans with intellisense support

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, intellisense, syntax-highlighting

Is there possible to edit .htaccess files with **Intellisense** and syntax highlighting support in Eclipse, Aptana or Netbeans (may be plugins)?

mod-rewrite syntax support is cool feature!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vote for this issue to get it added to a future version of Netbeans: [link](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166364)

Answer (score 0):

You can go [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364152/how-to-color-highlight-htaccess-files-in-eclipse) to look about syntax highlighting.

As far as I am concerned, I don't think Intellisense feature (meaning autocompletion) would be very interesting for mod_rewrite.

I mean basically all the Rules are `RewriteRule` or `RewriteCond` and the rest is really dependant of your directories. Even the variables are not so difficult to remember;